# Material UI react autocomplete set different label and different value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

we can see the example here at https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/

I wanted to set option label and value different.

Like here is example used

```js
    const defaultProps = {
       options: top5Films,
       getOptionLabel: (option) => option.title,
    };

    <Autocomplete
      {...defaultProps}
      id="auto-complete"
      value={value}
      onChange={(event, newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue);
      }}
      autoComplete
      includeInputInList
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="clearOnEscape" margin="normal"/>}
    />
    const top5Films= [
    { title: 'The Shawshank Redemption', year: 1994 },
    { title: 'The Godfather', year: 1972 },
    { title: 'The Godfather: Part II', year: 1974 },
    { title: 'The Dark Knight', year: 2008 },
    { title: '12 Angry Men', year: 1957 }
    ]
```

But I have data like:

```js
const top5Films= [
    { id: 1, title: 'The Shawshank Redemption', year: 1994 },
    { id: 2, title: 'The Godfather', year: 1972 },
    { id: 3, title: 'The Godfather: Part II', year: 1974 },
    { id: 4, title: 'The Dark Knight', year: 2008 },
    { id: 5, title: '12 Angry Men', year: 1957 }
    ]
```

I want to set id as value and show title as label.

Comment: so what's happening when you start typing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the object is assigned to the value.

So setting id to value crashed the options.

I used the id from the object in following way for further operation.

```js
/* eslint-disable no-use-before-define */
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";

export default function Playground() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);
  const [id, setId] = React.useState(null);
  const [title, setTitle] = React.useState(null);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{`value: ${value}`}</div>
      <div>{`id: ${id}`}</div>
      <div>{`title: ${title}`}</div>

      <br />
      <div style={{ width: 300 }}>
        <Autocomplete
          options={top5Films}
          getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
          id="movies"
          value={value}
          onChange={(event, newValue) => {
            console.log(newValue);
            if (newValue) {
              setValue(newValue);
              setId(newValue.id);
              setTitle(newValue.title);
            }
          }}
          renderInput={params => (
            <TextField {...params} label="Movies" margin="normal" />
          )}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

// Top 5 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top5Films = [
  { id: 1, title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { id: 2, title: "The Godfather", year: 1972 },
  { id: 3, title: "The Godfather: Part II", year: 1974 },
  { id: 4, title: "The Dark Knight", year: 2008 },
  { id: 5, title: "12 Angry Men", year: 1957 }
];
```

This works for now but best answer is always welcome.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't find the change from what I had posted.
Looks like the value is the object and cannot set that to id because that will crash the option.
Maybe I need to obtain id from the object later before sending to the backend.

Comment: here is the sandbox i am playing around: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-x02jd?file=/demo.js

Comment: @yathomasi what's the problem there?

Comment: i want to send id to the backend but the value is an object

Comment: yes i tried similar. you can see in the codesandbox mentioned above.
I tried editing on your answer it giving queue error.

Comment: @yathomasi see https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-bi2ob?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/demo.js

Answer (score 1):

okk you can try in this way -

```js
  const options = [
    {
      id: 212,
      label: 'First Title'
    },
    {
      id: 321,
      label: 'Second Title'
    },
    {
      id: 543,
      label: 'Third Title'
    }
  ]
  
  <Autocomplete
      placeholder="Search…"
      options={options}
      isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.id === value.id}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label={'label'} />}
      renderOption={(props, option) => {
          return (
              <li {...props}>
                {option.label}
              </li>
             )
           }}
      onChange={(_event, value) => {
          setValue(value.id)
      }}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't fully understand your issue but I guess you want to have different display option for getOptionLabel and different display in the dropdown list. If that's the case, you can simply use renderOption provided by the Material UI. Check out an example here : https://codesandbox.io/s/94xlp?file=/demo.js

```
import React from "react";
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import { Autocomplete } from "@material-ui/lab";

  return (
   <Autocomplete
                            freeSolo
                            name=""
                            options={top5Films }
                            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title} //Displays title only in input field
                            renderOption={(option) => (
                              <React.Fragment>
                                {option.title + "," + " " + option.year}  //Displays title + year in dropdown list
                              </React.Fragment>
                            )}
                            renderInput={params => (
                              <Field
                                component={FormikTextField}
                                {...params}
                                label=""
                                name=""
                              />
                            )}
                          />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, set a json value and use the name for inputValue, the input value not change why not calling onChange function

```html
<Autocomplete
  options={machineList}
  inputValue={formValues.machine.name || ""} // from formik context in my case
  onChange={(e, value) => {
    setValues(
      "machine",
      value && value.id ? { id: value.id, name: value.name } : ""  //use json value
    );
  }}
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <InputField
      {...params}
      type="text"
      name={machine.name}
      label={machine.label}
      fullWidth
    />
  )}
/>;
```